# Where I can find standard Ubuntu icons?

Tags: icons

I need icons which is near the name of program in left-top corner (for nautilus and text editor). And icons for text file and catalog in nautilus. It is for my site.

Comment: Did you look in `/usr/share/icons` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but you can use the `find` command in a terminal:

```
[sudo] find directory -name '*.png'
```

where

- `sudo` should be omitted as long as not necessary
- `directory` is where you want to recursively start the search.

This is of course subject to all variations you need. To search the directory mentionned by user535733:

```
find /usr/share/icons -name '*.png'
```

To search your whole system:

```
sudo find / -name '*.png'
```

Use with care and help yourself a coffee while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, system icons are available in `/usr/share/icons` directory.
The standard Ubuntu icon theme is called Yaru and it is installed by the package `yaru-theme-icon`. This package puts the Yaru icons in `/usr/share/icons/Yaru`

Another way to get these icons (useful if you don't have access to an Ubuntu system) consists in going to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru) of the Yaru project. Clicking the green button labeled <kbd>Code</kbd> and selecting <kbd>Download Zip</kbd>, you can download the archive, then extract it to access to the icon directory.

Generally speaking, another directoy where icons may be placed are `${HOME}/.icons` or in `${HOME}/.local/share/icons`. You may find there all the icons pack that are manually installed by the user not by apt/synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

You want `gtk3-icon-browser`

You will probably have to install gtk-3-examples.

`sudo apt install gtk-3-examples`

As you stated, this will only give you "standard" icons. There won't be any vendor specific icons.

*This application only gives you the name and available sizes of the icon so you can search it (like with the methods in the other answers. ie /usr/share/icons)... The only extra benefit is that it provides somewhat of a categorized database that you can search.*